# iPhone UIImage loaded from core data is rotated counterclockwise by 90 degrees. How to fix?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, uiimage

I'm capturing an image from camera using AVCaptureSession:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

The image gets converted into a UIImage and is added to an image view. The image is displayed in a portrait orientation, as expected.

I'm trying to save the image into core data between capture sessions. My core data entity has an image property with binary data type.

```
coreDataEntity.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
```

Once the user reloads a previously saved session, the image view has its image restored using:

```
 imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:coreDataEntity.image];
```

However, the restored image is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise with it's top pointing to the left.

**At which point does the image get rotated?** Is it during saving or during loading from core data?

I have a method to rotate a UIImage by 90 degrees, but it appears that on subsequent re-loading of the same image, it gets rotated by extra 90 degrees. How can I know that I've already rotated a UIImage once?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You may want to see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3554244/1228534

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a year you have probably solved this yourself, but I have experienced this problem myself recently and thought I would put up my solution.

I changed the stored image format to JPEG.

change

```
coreDataEntity.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
```

to

```
coreDataEntity.image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,1.0f);
```

The image is restored as before

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:coreDataEntity.image];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't force a format in the database. By converting to a PNG before storing it in the database, you are removing information that is probably needed (like orientation).

If my hypothesis is correct, try to serialize the UIImage like this instead:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:image]
```

and deserialize with this

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:imageData]
```

Also, be sure to check out [`NSValueTransformer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which can encapsulate this conversion so that you never have to deal with it once it's working.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to encapsulate with NSValueTransformer? I don't really understand that step.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
```

instead of

```
let imageData = image.pngData()
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's neither during the load or save. I find it suspicious that you have a method that rotates the image by 90 degrees and that's just what's happening to your image. Try modifying your method to rotate by a different angle (zero for example) and see of it affects your bug. I suspect your rotate method is called and you don't know it.

Another possibility is that you hold your iPhone/iPad in landscape when you take your photo but your app does not support device rotation.

There's really not much info in your post so I'm just fishing here :)

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion! I got the rotation method after I discovered that bug, so it's not the fault of the rotation method. Rather I wanted to use it to remedy the issue once I found the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 > : before saving the image as pngData() call this function and use the returned image here:

```
 func rotatedCopy() -> UIImage {
    if self.imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.up {
        return self
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    //draws the image in current context respecting orientation
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return copy!
 }
```