# How do I save a UIImage to a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

If I have a `UIImage` from an imagePicker, how can I save it to a subfolder in the documents directory?

Answer (score 135):

Of course you can create subfolders in the documents folder of your app. You use [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do that.

You use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert your image to NSData and save that to disk.

```
// Create path.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];

// Save image.
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Core Data has nothing to do with saving images to disk by the way.

Comment: You lose all orientation information by using UIImagePNGRepresentation.

Comment: so how can I save images without losing information?

Comment: @Pol you can either save it as UIImageJPEGRepresentation or fix the orientation yourself, various solutions in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554244/uiimagepngrepresentation-issues-images-rotated-by-90-degrees

Answer (score 26):

In Swift 3:

```
// Create path.
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let filePath = "\(paths[0])/MyImageName.png"

// Save image.
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
```

Comment: No longer valid -- you need to use `.write() throws`

Answer (score 25):

You have to [construct a representation of your image as a particular format](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) (say, JPEG or PNG), and then call `writeToFile:atomically:` on the representation:

```
UIImage *image = ...;
NSString  *path = ...;
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 18):

The above are useful, but they don't answer your question of how to save in a subdirectory or get the image from a UIImagePicker.

First, you must specify that your controller implements image picker's delegate, in either .m or .h code file, such as:

```
@interface CameraViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Then you implement the delegate's imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method, which is where you can get the photograph from the image picker and save it (of course, you may have another class/object that handles the saving, but I'll just show the code inside the method):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // get the captured image
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *imageSubdirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MySubfolderName"];

    NSString *filePath = [imageSubdirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImageName.png"];

    // Convert UIImage object into NSData (a wrapper for a stream of bytes) formatted according to PNG spec
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

If you want to save as JPEG image, the last 3 lines would be:

```
NSString *filePath = [imageSubdirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImageName.jpg"];

// Convert UIImage object into NSData (a wrapper for a stream of bytes) formatted according to JPG spec
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.85f); // quality level 85%
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 14):

```
extension UIImage {
    /// Save PNG in the Documents directory
    func save(_ name: String) {
        let path: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent(name)
        try! UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)?.write(to: url)
        print("saved image at \(url)")
    }
}

// Usage: Saves file in the Documents directory
image.save("climate_model_2017.png")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

where path is the name of the file you want to write it to.

Answer (score 5):

First you should get the Documents directory

```
/* create path to cache directory inside the application's Documents directory */
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName"];
```

Then you should save the photo to the file

```
NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImage, 1);
[photoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4.2:

```
// Create path.
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
if let filePath = paths.first?.appendingPathComponent("MyImageName.png") {
    // Save image.
    do {
       try image.pngData()?.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
    } catch {
       // Handle the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4:

```
// Create path.
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
if let filePath = paths.first?.appendingPathComponent("MyImageName.png") {
    // Save image.
    do {
       try UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
    }
    catch {
       // Handle the error
    }
}
```