# Is there any way to dynamically compress an UIImage in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have tried image resize plugin to compress image in my app. But it reduces the clarity and it doesn't look good. Can anyone please tell me any other solution to compress image dynamically in my iPhone application.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIImage (Resize)
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size;
@end


#import "UIImage+Resize.h"


// Put this in UIImageResizing.m
@implementation UIImage (Resize)

- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: If you want the image compressed, convert it to a [file image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11592313/581994) as a PNG or JPEG.  You don't have to actually save the file image, you can keep it as NSData to restore quickly to UIImage.

Comment: And [this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6064453/581994) will half-size an image with minimal loss of detail.

Comment: @HotLicks Interesting. But is it actually better than using a system method? Any rationale for this approach?

Comment: I tried several "system methods" and all produced an inferior image.