# How to save Image with its custom name in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to capture image from image picker controller and save image with its custom name and later on fetch all the images with their respective names .

Comment: you can create folder with your app name, and get all photos from it

Comment: I think the question was asked before 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592313/how-do-i-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

try this

````
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let filePath = "\(paths[0])/MyImageName.png"

// Save image.
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the picker working in order to get an image from the gallery, and only wants to save and get it from the app folder.

I was able to make this with the following code:

Class ImagePersistance.swift

```
open class ImagePersistance: NSObject {

    var fileManager: FileManager
    var documentsURL: URL
    var documentPath: String

    public override init() {
        self.fileManager = FileManager.default
        self.documentsURL =  self.fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        self.documentPath = documentsURL.path
    }

    public func saveImage(image: UIImage?, name: String) throws {

        if image != nil {
            let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(String(name)).png")

            if let currentImage = image {
                if let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentImage) {
                    try pngImageData.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public func getImage(name: String) -> UIImage? {

        let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(String(name)).png")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {

            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath.path) {
               return image
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

How to use it:

Save image:

```
do {
     try ImagePersistance().saveImage(image: IMAGE_HERE, name: "IMAGE_NAME")
   catch {
     print("image error")
   }
```

Get saved image

```
let image:UIImage = ImagePersistance().getImage(name: "IMAGE_NAME")
```