# Rotation of images stored in documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have written an app that allows the user to take photos which are stored in an `NSArray` and which are then saved in the `Documents directory`. When they are reloaded the pictures are stored in an `UITableView` - note only one photo is currently loaded due to problem 1.

I have two problems:

1 - This works but only for one photo as I need to be able work out how many photos have been stored.

2 - When I reload the data and put into an `UIImageView` the rotation of the photos is incorrect. Landscape photos are upside down and portrait photos are landscape.

Any help with either of these issues greatly appreciated.

**Saving the photos**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

for (int i=0;i<photoCount;i++)
{
    UIImage *image = [photos objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *savePicturePath = [saveFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d",i]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savePicturePath atomically:NO];
}
```

**Retrieving the photos**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getPicPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_0"];
NSData *picData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:getPicPath];

UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:picData];
[photos addObject:loadedImage];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**Adding image to table**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
UIImage *currentImage = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = currentImage;
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve the first issue by creating your own directory and storing all images to that directory. Then when you read use `NSFileManager's contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` to get an array of all the images in that directory. Or you could read the content of the documents folder and use NSPredicate to filter out only images by file extension (using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`).

As for the rotation issue, the answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554244/uiimagepngrepresentation-issues-images-rotated-by-90-degrees).

Comment: Thanks. I fact I do create a folder for the images but I removed the code here to keep it from being too lengthy. I will look into contentsOfDirectoryAtPath - am I right in thinking it returns an array of the directory contents? The other answer explains things very well - thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation issue ... simple:

Change

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

to

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

And everything is perfect. Thanks to Joel for pointing me in the right direction.