# Image rotation In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I am using **Xcode 7.3** and **ojective-c** one of my application when I am converting the ***camera image into base64 then image will be rotation 90 degree left*** I try so many method to fix this issue but did not working any one.

> Below are the code:

```
NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@", [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]];
```

**I try all the orientation by this ways but it's not working:**

```
CGImageRef cgRef = image.CGImage;
   image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
    UIImage *originalImage = image;
```

Comment: How did you find that you have to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with `data:image/png` ??

Comment: hi #NeverHopeless i found this on stackoverflow data:image/png and jpeg also .

Comment: the problem in conversion of  base64 because after converting capture image into base64 it will rotate the image position but if i picked from gallery then it will work fine.

Comment: Have you tried `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with data:image/**jpg**

Comment: yes I tried It's not working

Comment: after encode i am using this tool : http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter to see the image position

Comment: I don't no why it's only happen when i pick image using camera.

Comment: I am having the same issue.Have you fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  -  (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(UIImage*)oldImage deg:(CGFloat)degrees
   {
//Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height)];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

//Create the bitmap context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

//Rotate the image context
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, (degrees * M_PI / 180));

//Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-oldImage.size.width / 2, -oldImage.size.height / 2, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height), [oldImage CGImage]);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
   }
```

Comment: hi #rahul the problem in base64 conversation on ImageView selected image look good but after convert into base64 it will rotate.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554244/uiimagepngrepresentation-issues-images-rotated-by-90-degrees?lq=1), PNG format has a known issue with rotation, I would suggest you to try `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with `data:image/jpg;` instead of `data:image/png;`. This way it will probably set the rotation flag.

Hope it helps!

Comment: NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpg;,%@", [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]];

Answer (score -1):

You can save to your app and get image from memory to view with code:

```
- (UIImage *)finishSavePhotoWithImagePickerController:(NSDictionary *()info {

    UIImage *editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToSave = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToSave = originalImage;
    }

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 1.0);
    [imageData writeToFile:@"yourFilePath" options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone error:nil];
    UIImage *showImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"yourFilePath"];
    return showImage;
}
```