# UIImage automatically rotated when loaded from Filemanager

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

When I take picture in **Portrait Mode**, `savedImage` is automatically rotated when setting to `UIImageView`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProfilePicture.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

UIImage *savedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
```

But when I use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation: writeToFile: atomically:` method, the result Image has No Issues.

Can anyone please explain why I didn't get image in correct orientation while using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` & not in `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

NB: I tried

```
UIImage *imageToDisplay =
     [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
              scale:[originalImage scale]
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

to save `imageToDisplay`, but not working

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the rotation flag in EXIF data of the JPEG. every image file has metadata property. If the metadata specifies the orientation of the image which is generally ignored by other OS but Mac. Most of images taken are having their meta data property set to right angle. So Mac shows it 90 degree rotated manner. You can see the same image in proper way in windows OS. please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868914/7456236) answer which shows more details